# Web.Debug.config is NOT transforming the connectionstrings to the Web.config in MVC 5 projects

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web-config

I have created a new VS 2015 web project  MVC5.   By default I can see the **Web.config** and **Web.Debug.config**

Reading several articles, I really don't see what I really need to do in order to have it take my values from Web.Debug.config and replace the current Web.config.

I've been looking at another project at work that does this and it works fine, but I'm been through a lot of properties and settings and I don't see what is different.

I can Right click on Web.Debug.config and Preview and it shows me that it will REPLACE "test" with "10.10.10.10"  so it seems good to me (like it should work  but running project it DOES NOT change the value)

Example

Project :

Debug  / Any CPU  ,   run google chrome   , problem is that **Data source** is NOT getting changed

**Web.Debug.config**

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Envy" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="EnvyIdentity" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="DNNSmartstore" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="DNNPos" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=DevFood_POS;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Envy" connectionString="Data Source=test\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="EnvyIdentity" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="DNNSmartstore" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="DNNPos" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=DevFood_POS;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Are you building it in Release? If so it uses the Web.Release.config not the Debug one

Comment: I'm not using Release.  Locally another project that I didn't create, I can see that when I change Web.debug.config , then click on "Play" (run) in Debug and the web.config does get updated, while my application is not , I am not seeing any code anywhere within configs or in properties, any sort of msbuild stuff added  - OH WAIT , i should look in the csproj file   , hang on

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Out of the box, transformations (debug/release) are applied on **publishing** (deploy). Not on build, on deploy.

To make this happen on build you may need to do some manual edits of the project file. Take a look here fore example: https://gist.github.com/EdCharbeneau/9135216

Comment: ok,  see my comment to the others,   maybe the edit of the csproj file,  that might have the msbuild stuff added in i hope

Comment: <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.template.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
  </Target>

Comment: Above is what the other project had that made it work, so between that and your article I can figure it out  , cool   thx

Comment: Ed Charbeneau's process works, but I now have the problem that transformations are doubly-applied on publishing (deploy). Anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 13):

So close but **BACKWARDS**. For this case use **Web.config** and **Web.Release.config** only.

Put all your Debug settings in **Web.config**, put your Release settings in **Web.Release.config**, and do not use **Web.Debug.config**. Debugging will happen using the regular Web.config, and only released builds will get the Release settings.

from your example above:

**Web.config**

```
<!-- test/debug settings in regular web.config -->
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Envy" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="EnvyIdentity" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="DNNSmartstore" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="DNNPos" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=DevFood_POS;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>       
      </connectionStrings>
```

**Web.Release.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Envy" connectionString="Data Source=test\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="EnvyIdentity" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="DNNSmartstore" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=myDB;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="DNNPos" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.10\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=DevFood_POS;user id=myLoginID;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Web.Debug.config** is a place to put settings that you want to apply when you deploy to a test server. The name is pretty misleading at first.  The only place I ever use this feature is if I have a Test server which needs different settings from my Dev box. :-)